# Dans quels cas peut-on remplacer «qui» par «lequel» ?

Tags: pronoms, pronoms-relatifs

Est-ce qu'on peut remplacer «qui» par «lequel» même si l'antécédent est une personne ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Oui, d'après la définition de [lequel](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/lequel) sur CNRTL :

> […] En dehors de l'emploi prépositionnel, le pronom relatif introduit toujours une proposition relative explicative et remplace facultativement *qui* (plus rarement *que*). […] *Un mauvais garnement nommé Giletti, **lequel** à la ville jouait les troisièmes rôles de valet* […]

Comment: Ça ne répond pas à la question qui est dans le titre. (Laquelle n'a vraisemblablement pas de réponse courte…)

Comment: Au contraire, cela est tout à fait ce que j'ai voulu savoir ... Merci

Answer (score 2):

Oui … [mais](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pronom_relatif#Syntaxe_du_pronom_.C2.AB_lequel_.C2.BB) …

Je pense qu'on doit examiner trois choses :

1. Complément direct vs. complément indirect
2. Préposition introduisant la proposition subordonnée relative
3. Être vivant vs. chose

En bref, c'est plutôt lorsqu'un antécédent *complément objet indirect* est introduit par une préposition qui n'est pas « de » qu'on utilise : *lequel*, *laquelle*, *lesquels*, *lesquelles*.

Par exemple :

> C'est le garçon *avec lequel* j'ai vu le film.   (COI / avec / être vivant)
>
> C'est le garçon *à qui* j'ai montré le film.      (COI / à    / être vivant)

Comment: J'ai trouvé un bon référence que j'utilise souvent (c'est de Héléne Weinachter, Le Point du FLE) http://www.lepointdufle.net/ccount/click.php?id=22